# Set text colour based on input type 'select'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set the colour of my text with class t1 with a colour value depending on what select option is chosen. This is the code I have got to:

```
$('#colour').on('change', function(){
 $('.t1').css('color', ':selected").val()');
});

  <select id="colour">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
```

Even if I try with something like this it doesn't work:

```
$('#colour').on('change', function(){
 $('.t1').css('color', 'red');
});
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work because you're trying to change the color **literally** to `:selected").val()`. Your "Even if I try with something like this" would work just fine, assuming there are elements with the class `t1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to catch the current selection of the `select-box` with `.val()` function.

`this` keyword refers to the `select-box` while the `val()` function is displaying actual selection.

```js
$('#colour').on('change', function() {
  $('.t1').css('background', $(this).val());
});
```

```css
.t1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colour">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>

<div class='t1'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Within an event handler callback for a form field, `this` refers to the field. So `$(this).val()` gives you the value:

```js
$('#colour').on('change', function() {
  $('.t1').css('color', $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<select id="colour">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
<div class="t1">I'm a t1</div>
<div class="t1">So am I</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working when you add your code to the `onchange` event of HTML.

```js
function onchangeevent(){
 $('.t1').css('color', 'red');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colour" onchange="onchangeevent()">
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
</select>
<div class="t1">
text
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work properly. It changes the color only once.

Comment: ohh, then this is an incomplete answer, I just tried the second part when user said that even this didn't worked...

Comment: It's all good, but would be even better if you improve your answer (:

Comment: i'm on it... :)

Comment: this is weird... this [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lys9vgf7/1/) throws console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at jQuery.fn.init.val (jquery-3.1.1.js:7905)
    at onchangeevent (VM2759:46)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onchange ((index):59)`. I don't understand why...

Comment: You can't use `this` keyword in this way, because as far as I know, in this particular case, `this` will refer to the window object, not `t1` element.

Comment: okay idk why but setting jQuery to load at `OnLoad` instead of `No wrap in head` worked fine for me. see [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lys9vgf7/2/). Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Now it's quite different situation, because you are using `on()` jQuery function and now, `this` keyword references to the `colour` element :)